# toExponential() Method not working

Tags: javascript, function, methods

toExponential() Method is not working my code.
chrome console is giving this error:
Uncaught TypeError: number.toExponential is not a function.
Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>JS Code Academy</title>
</head>
<body>

<input type="number" id="myInput" value="2.326">

<button id="myButton">Click Me!</button>

<p id="demo1"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>


<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = function() {

var number = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
var str = number.toExponential(2);

document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = str;
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = typeof str;
};
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `var number = Number(document.getElementById("myInput").value);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`toExponential` is a method defined on the number class. So make sure that you are calling it on a number and not a string:

```
var value = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
var number = parseFloat(value);
if (!isNaN(number)) {
    // The string value entered in the textbox was successfully parsed to a number
    // we can now calculate the exponential:
    var str = number.toExponential(2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `<input type="number" id="myNumber" />` , the entry must be just numbers so it will be easier for users to work with it. Darin's code is a good solution.